# Directive not working outside a component

Tags: typescript, angular, angular2-directives

I have an Angular 2 `Directive` as follows:

```
import { DOM } from 'angular2/src/platform/dom/dom_adapter';
import {Directive, ElementRef, Renderer} from 'angular2/core'

@Directive({
    selector: '[headerBG]',
    host: {
        '(click)': 'onClick()'
    }
})
export class HeaderBGDirective {

    constructor(private el: ElementRef, private renderer: Renderer) {   
    }
    onClick() {
        console.log(1234);
    }
}
```

If I apply this to `body` element:

```
<body headerBG>
```

it does not work.

But if I put it inside another component, it works fine:

```
@Component({
selector: 'courses',
template: `<h2>
            {{title}}
            <input type='text' headerBG/>
          </h2>
          <ul>
              <li *ngFor="#course of courses">
              {{course}}
              </li>
          </ul>
          `,
          providers: [CourseService],
          directives: [HeaderBGDirective]
})
```

Is this the correct behavior or am I missing something? How do I apply the directive to the `body` element without making it a component?

**EDIT:**

```
import {Component} from 'angular2/core';
import {HeaderComponent} from 'modules/shared/directives/header.component';
import {HeaderBGDirective} from 'modules/shared/directives/headerBG.directive';

@Component({
    selector: 'body',
    templateUrl: './welcome/templates/welcome.html',
    directives: [HeaderComponent, HeaderBGDirective]
})
export class AppComponent {
    post = {
        title: 'Favorite',
        isFavorite: true
    }
 }
```

In `welcome.html`:

```
<sc-header></sc-header><div>some content</div>
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Angular directives are not supposed to be used outside components. The root of an Angular2 application is a component instantiated by

```
bootstrap(AppComponent)
```

Other components and directives work only inside such a root component or descendant components of this root component.

Comment: Thanks. So, looks like I have to bootstrap the app on `body`, but it seems to be a limiting point of Angular2 for me.

Comment: Does that mean I can never put a directive in `body` tag, since the root app should be contained somewhere(which I think should be body). Or can I do something like this:`    <html>
        <head></head>
        <my-app>
        </my-app>
    </html>`. And then put `body` in the `my-app`?

Comment: There are some limitations compared to Angular1. Angular2 is a lot about performance and they had to make some compromises.

Comment: You can just use `'body'` as selector for your root component.

Comment: I used `body` as selector but I had to move another component inside the `template` file for `body` and now the page loads except the component which I moved in. Am I doing something wrong.

Comment: Hard to tell without more details. It definitely should work.

Comment: Earlier: `<body><my-header></my-header><my-app></my-pp></body>`.
Now: `<body></body>` and in template: `<my-header></my-header><div>some content</div>`

Comment: The `MyHeader` class might be missing in the directives `@Component({selector: 'body', directives: [MyApp, MyHeader], ...})`

Answer (score 1):

I think this is a bootstrapping issue.  When you bootstrap angular 2, you specify the application component

In the example below taken from https://github.com/johnpapa/angular2-tour-of-heroes/blob/master/app/main.ts, `AppComponent` as a selector of `my-app`.  So it finds the element that matches the selector and is scoped to only that element (and its decedents).

```
import { bootstrap }    from 'angular2/platform/browser';
import { AppComponent } from './app.component';

bootstrap(AppComponent);
```

So your application component would need to have a selector of `body` for this to work.  There could be problems with selecting `body`, but I haven't tried it to know for sure.